# query about how to use the "raise" keyword in python

Tags: python

This code is borrowed from the book DATA STRUCTURE AND ALGORITHMS IN PYTHON by Michael t. Goodrich.

```
class ArrayStack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data=[]

    def __len__(self):

        return len(self.data)

    def is_empty(self):

        return len(self.data)==0

    def push(self,e):

        self.data.append(e)

    def top(self):

        if self.is_empty():
            
            raise Empty('Stack is empty')
         
        else:
            return self.data[-1]

    def pop(self):

        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Stack is empty')
        else:
            return self.data.pop()
```

Here, the author uses `raise Empty("stack is empty')` to raise an error message, but the "Empty" keyword isn't proper to be used with raise, and it instead throws `NameError` when i run the program. I don't get why the author used it here instead of using the `Exception` keyword with raise.

It has been used in every data structure in this book , so i don't think it's a typing error.(I apologize if i am missing something basic)

Comment: Is it possible the author defined the `Empty` exception earlier in the text?

Comment: `class Empty(Exception): pass` should do it.

Comment: Looking at the code this implementation gives zero value compared for the list used internally. It just renames stuff.

Answer (score 4):

The book defines the `Empty` class in "Fragment 6.1" in chapter 6 of the book.  The description of this fragment is:

> Code Fragment 6.1: Definition for an Empty exception class.

and the fragment itself is:

```
class Empty(Exception):
    """Error attempting to access an element from an empty container."""
    pass
```

Later sections of the book that make use of this class reference this code fragment.